# ServletContext for GrizzlyTestContainer

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jersey-test-framework

Is it possible for TestContainer to receive data from ServletContext as in the following case?

```
public class LinkResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(LinkResource.class);

        config.register(StatusResponseFilter.class);
        config.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        config.register(ExceptionMapperFeature.class);
        config.register(JacksonContextResolver.class);
        config.register(DatabaseFeature.class);

        return config;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {
        config.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

The `config.register(DatabaseFeature.class);` line makes trouble because DatabaseFeature needs a ServletContext in the constructor, which I have for production.

```
public class DatabaseFeature implements Feature {
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public DatabaseFeature(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new DatabaseBinding(servletContext));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is make sure that the test is running in a servlet environment. To do that you need to override the `getTestContainerFactory()` and `configureDeployment()` methods of the `JerseyTest` and return a web test container and a `ServletDeploymentContext`, respectively. Look at the apis for `ServletDeploymentContext` to see different ways to create the `DeploymentContext`. for the `getTestContainerFactory()` you will probably return `GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory`.

Comment: You will nee the dependency for the [grizzly servlet provider](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers/jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2)